# Reverting a commit that's been accepted to GitHub, then making a small modifiation and trying again

Tags: git, github

I committed some code on a local branch and opened a pull request on our GitHub repo, which was accepted.  Only then did we realize that we shouldn't have made change X, so we need to revert and try again.

I haven't reverted an accepted PR and wondered how best to go about it here.  I know GitHub has a revert button on closed pull requests but subsequent steps are...?

Do I revert, then pull from the 'master' branch (the one that had the PR accepted) into my local branch?  Won't I lose my work then?  Or should I open a new branch, pull into that one, and then cherry pick my original commits, then modify from there and open a new PR?

This is revert 101 stuff I know but I just haven't had to do it often.

Answer (score 1):

Just revert the pull request, then pull from the master branch as you suggest. Reverting in git **does not delete** your original commits. It simply creates additional commits that *undo* the originals.

This means your commits will still be in master, so you can cherry-pick them and rebase them however you like.